# I am looking for a way via XSLT to pull nested Wordml child tables out from under the parent

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a Word document that contains nested tables (parent tables and child tables). I want to pull out the child tables and toss aside the parent tables but can't figure out a way to do so using xslt in oXygen.

```
    w:tbl
          w:tbl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, use the identity transformation template plus

```
<xsl:template match="w:tbl[.//w:tbl]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=".//w:tbl"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I am not familiar with the WordML table structure, obviously if the `tbl` elements are direct children then using `w:tbl[w:tbl]` instead of `w:tbl[.//w:tbl]` and `w:tbl` instead of `.//w:tbl` suffices.

Comment: absolutely perfect. worked beautifully! thanks for the assist.

Comment: @randola: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.